# Quarkus: Set Multiple TestProfiles to class?

Tags: testing, quarkus

I am currently writing some tests for my application in quarkus. It processes some data, therefore a small number of my tests take a long time to finish. They basically test the processing of large amount of data.

I then discovered test profiles, which would allow me to run specific tests only. I wanted to create only two categories, "fast" and "slow". However, then I thought that it might come in handy to also differentiate between unit and integration tests. However its not possible to create a test class like so:

```java
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(FastProfile.class)
@TestProfile(UnitProfile.class)
public class ConnectionProviderUnitTest {
}
```

This gives an error on compile: `io.quarkus.test.junit.TestProfile is not a repeatable annotation type`

Of course I could just create four profiles "FastUnit", "SlowUnit", "FastIntegration" and "SlowIntegration" and define them like so:

```java
public class SlowIntegrationProfile implements QuarkusTestProfile {
    @Override
    public Set<String> tags() {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("integration", "slow"));
    }
}
```

However I suspect other profiles might come in in the future, e.g. testing only a specific group of beans together or what not. It would be impractical to create a completely new Profile every time and adapt the existing ones. It would be very nice if I could just repeat the annotation or just give it a list of profiles to work with. Is this possible?

Comment: instead of having 2 testprofile try to use tags as explained [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#running-specific-tests)

Comment: Thats what I did... what do you mean "to use tags"? I don't see a way, how I can directly associate a test with a tag without using test profiles...